# How can you use a color selector drawable to tint an imageview pre-lollipop

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have an imageview declared like so:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/login_settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:tint="@drawable/cl_button_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/login_show_password"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_settings" />
```

and the drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" 
        android:color="@color/colorButtonDisabled"/>
    <item android:color="@color/colorButtonNormal"/>
</selector>
```

This works correctly on newer devices

When I run it on an Android 4.4 emulator I get the error:

```
Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class ImageView ---> Java.Lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "res/drawable/cl_button_text.xml"
```

When I change the view to :

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/login_settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:tint="@color/colorButtonNormal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/login_show_password"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_settings" />
```

It works correctly (ofc the tint does not change according to the imageview's state)

Is there something I can do? preferably from the xml and not programmatically?

Comment: Try using AppCompatImageView instead of ImageView and `app:tint` instead of `android:tint`

Comment: I've already tried it, doesn't work, I get the message that : `No resource identifier found for attribute 'tint' in package 'my package'`

Comment: change "tint" to "background"
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/login_settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cl_button_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/login_show_password"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_settings" />

Comment: no that does nothing, drawable still shows in its original color (i.e. black)

Comment: It's because you're using a regular Imageview instead of AppCompatImageView

Comment: yeah but it's supposed to be replaced with an appcompat version if you're using the compatibility framework

Comment: Only if you are using an AppCompat Activity

Comment: As for the `No resource identifier found` message, make sure you're using at least version 25.4.0 of the support library. The `tint` attribute wasn't added until then.

Comment: yeah that may be the case, I haven't updated the packages in a while, I'm using Xamarin and I'm afraid to update support packages, I'll try that, it should work, thank you

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:tint)

`android:tint`

> May be a color value, in the form of "#rgb", "#argb", "#rrggbb", or "#aarrggbb".

So you can not use drawable resource in xlm

You can try it with [this sollution](https://orcchg.wordpress.com/2016/02/28/how-to-tint-a-drawable/)